# connect child nodes with dotted connector when showRoot="false" in dojo tree

Tags: dojo

I am trying to create a tree using dojo where the root node need not be displayed but the children should be connected using dotted connectors. Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

see `dijit.Tree`. widget

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tree.html